# How to create argument variable in bash script

Tags: bash, unix

I am trying to write a script such that I can identify number of characters of the n-th largest file in a sub-directory. 
I was trying to assign n and the name of sub-directory into arguments like $1, $2.

```
Current directory: Greetings
   Sub-directory: language_files, others
     Sub-directory: English, German, French
          Files: Goodmorning.csv, Goodafternoon.csv, Goodevening.csv ….
```

I would be at directory “Greetings”, while I indicating subdirectory (English, German, French), it would show the nth-largest file in the subdirectory indicated and calculate number of characters as well.

For instance, if I am trying to figure out number of characters of 2nd largest file in English, I did:

```
langs=$1
n=$2
for langs in language_files/;
 Do count=$(find language_files/$1 name "*.csv" | wc -m | head -n -1 | sort -n -r | sed -n $2(p))
Done | echo "The file has $count bytes!"
```

The result I wanted was:

```
$ ./script1.sh English 2
The file has 1100 bytes!
```

The main problem of all the issue is the fact that I don't understand how variables and looping work in bash script.

Comment: So [start learning](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/InputAndOutput). The script is almost ok. Remainders: bash is case sensitive. `for` is not `For`.  To grab command output use command substitution. Even with `for`s! `count_bytes=$(for langs in language/*; do echo $langs; done)`. bash is space sensitive - `var='a'` will work, but `var = 'a'` will not! Use `wc -c` not `wc -m`, i think it doesn't do what you think.  bash uses `"` not `“`. And use dynamic programming - split your problem into many little problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no need for looping

```
find language_files/"$1" -name "*.csv" | xargs wc -m | sort -nr | sed -n "$2{p;q}"
```

for byte counting you should use `-c`, since `-m` is for char counting (it may be the same for you).

You don't use the loop variable in the script anyway.

Comment: Always an efficiency benefit from avoiding the loops.

Comment: What does {p;q} mean after $2?

Comment: Print and quit. To prevent scanning the rest of the lines.

Answer (score 0):

Bash loops are interesting. You are encouraged to learn more about them when you have some time. However, this particular problem might not need a loop. Set `lang` (you can call it `langs` if you prefer) and `n` appropriately, and then try this:

```
count=$(stat -c'%s %n' language_files/$lang/* | sort -nr | head -n$n | tail -n1 | sed -re 's/^[[:space:]]*([[:digit:]]+).*/\1/')
```

That should give you the $count you need. Then you can `echo` it however you like.

**EXPLANATION**

If you wish to learn how it works:

- The `stat` command outputs various statistics about the named file (or files), in this case `%s` the file's size and `%n` the file's name.
- The `head` and `tail` output respectively the first and last several lines of a file. Together, they select a specific line from the file
- The `sed` command screens a certain part of the line. (You can use `cut`, instead, if you prefer.)

If you wish to be cleverer, then you can optimize as @karafka has done.